# How to apply the same formula to a whole column?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How to subtracts the same values in the next cell to a whole column? Here is an example so you can understand my low English level.

```
Column 1    Column 2      Result 

1000         900           100
3400         200           3200
1700         100           1600
```

So, how can I subtrac automatically the number in column 2? I don't want to write each forumula for each row.

Hope you can edit my question if you understand my English.
I need you to edit my Table, I don't know to do make a table here. There are three columns here and three rows. I don't know how to arrange them.

Comment: Why aren't you using a simple formula for example `=A2-B2` on C2, then drag it down?

Comment: Because I don't want to do that each time. =A2-B2 on C2. A3-B3 on C3, them =A4-B4 on C4. And going. Maybe I don't understand what you are saying, or maybe I'm proposing something that doesn't exist.

Comment: You will enter the formula in C2, then drag it down using your mouse, not typing it.

Comment: How can I do that? Maybe a video would be better to learn this or perhaps you can try me here.

Comment: I need something like step by step

Comment: type in formula box example =SUM(J2:J21)

Answer (score 5):

1. Enter the formula to first cell.
2. Move your mouse to the bottom right of the cell the formula was entered on. The mouse pointer will change.
3. Click and hold, then move your mouse down. The formula will be replicated to the other cells.

[image]

Comment: In Excel you can highlight cell C1, C2 and C3, then press Ctrl + D. This effectively does the same, but with no mouse needed. Perhaps it also works here...?

Comment: @JenserCube It also works. I think you should post your comment as an alternative answer.

Comment: Can you also double-click (instead of dragging) like in excel?

Answer (score 2):

In case you prefer the keyboard over the mouse, you can do the following:

1. Highlight the cell that contains the formula you want to duplicate (you can do that simply by using arrow keys).
2. Once there, press Ctrl-C (copy).
3. Select the cell that you want to copy the formula to (again, can be achieved entirely by using arrow keys).
4. When you are there, press Ctrl-V (paste). Any references to cells are adjusted to match the position where you have added the formula (that is, if you are copying from, let's say, C2 to C3, the references to A2 and B2 are adjusted to point to A3 and B3 instead.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 as many times as required.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without mouse and copy/paste, through Ctrl + D.

Effectively Ctrl + D copies the content of the top most marked cell to the cells below. If only one cell is marked, the content of the cell right above is copied.
Usually I remember the D by thinking **D**own.

Ctrl + R has the same effect, but copying content from the **R**ight cell to all cells marked next to it.

1. Enter your formula into cell C1.
2. Hold shift and press the down arrow twice

   Cell C1, C2 and C3 should now be selected.
3. Press Ctrl + D.

Comment: I'm using a Mac, Ctrl + D := DELETES.

Comment: I don't have access to a Mac - what about Cmd + shift + D?

Comment: The only drawback of this method is that you cannot do it with non-adjacent cells. For contiguous blocks, no problem, though.